# Change color of Nine-Patch that's set as the background of a ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, nine-patch, android-constraintlayout

### Very mad question:

I'm trying to change the color of a Nine-Patch that's set as the background of a `ConstraintLayout`. `android:backgroundTint` in the XML works fine, but this is only supported by Android 5.0+. Using `app:backgroundTint` instead of `android:backgroundTint` doesn't change the color.

**My XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="29dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round"

    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/darker_gray">
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Does anyone know another way to change the color? **Any help is appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found the answer:

in the `onCreate()` method:

```
View line = findViewById(R.id.line);
ColorStateList tint = ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.holo_blue_light));
ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(line, tint);
```

Thanks to @azizbekian for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a framelayout like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="29dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round"

    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/darker_gray">

<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/framelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/whitebackground" // change the color as desired
          />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I think this will resolve your issue. Otherwise you can find a good library on Github.